# Screen is not clear white but bluish

Tags: display

I just noticed that my screen is a little bluish. Grey looks bluegrey and white is not a clear white. What should I do now? I don't know if it had always been like that. I noticed it because I was working on a website from another PC for a week and now I see the same website but more blue.

Comment: You don't describe anything about your hardware , operating system, extent of the problem, etc.  So people can talk generically about the kinds of things that you can explore, but nobody knows enough about your system to give you a specific solution.

Comment: I had this issue and fixed it by using color calibration.

Answer (score 2):

Monitor colors vary greatly. Think about when you go to a big box store with 100 televisions on display. Every picture has a slightly different look.

You can start with the physical buttons on your monitor and typically adjust brightness, contrast, and various other settings. There are typically setting for making the monitor "warmer" (redder) or "cooler" (bluer).

Windows has some built-in tools for assisting with color calibration. In Windows 10, if you hit the "Windows" key on your keyboard and start typing "calibrate display color" in the search box, you can open a tool that will step you through some screens that will guide you.

Professionals will purchase color calibration tools that help step through color correcting your monitors and/or printers. They can range from about $50 - thousands of dollars. Datacolor, X-Rite, Viewsonic, SpectraCal, are some current brands.

Answer (score 1):

Check your monitor settings (using the buttons on your monitor) to make sure the color mode is correct. It's possible to change how the monitor displays colors by changing the mode, the color temperature, RGB values, etc.

Comment: In addition there are also software color settings that can change and be changed. Check driver settings and install driver control panel if missing.

Comment: This is the simple solution and should be the first thing whenever you've got color issues. Nearly every monitor has color calibration settings and these are what you should check first.